# New tab chrome extension to redirect it to a specific website on opening a new tab

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

mainfest.json

```
{
    "name": "Get Some New Tab",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Replace new tab page with a minimal dashboard featuring motivation and simplicity.",
    
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
      "newtab": "https://tabdono.netlify.app/"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_security_policy": {
      "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';"
    },
    "permissions":["tabs"],
    
    "author": {
      "name": "Aditya Mittal",
      "url": "https://adityamittal.netlify.app/"
    }
  }
```

I want to redirect the user to the https://tabdono.netlify.app/ when they opens a new tab

Answer (score 0):

You want to detect the event of opening a new tab in `background.js` and redirect in the new tab event.

background.js:

```js
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {         
   chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "https://tabdono.netlify.app/"});
});
```

You need to add `background.js` to `manifest.json`.

```json
{
    ...
    background: {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```